# R Repeat function for every var and save results in a dataframe: where am I wrong?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), var2 = c(0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), var = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1), var3 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), var5 = c(0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ref = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to iterate the confusionMatrix function between each variable starting with "var" and the ref var.
Form each function application (each var) i would like to save the results in a new dataframe, as the following:

```
Variable Sensitivity
var1     1
var2     0.87
...
```

I have written the followin code:

```
library(Metrics)
k = grep("^var",colnames(data)) 
results<-as.data.frame(results <- lapply(k, FUN=function(x) {
  cm = confusionMatrix(data=as.factor(data$ref), reference=as.factor(data[[x]]))
  data.frame(
             variable=names(data)[x],
             Sensitivity = unname(cm$byClass[1])
            ) }))
```

I don't get errors, but the result is not that I want, as I get a data.frame like this

```
Variable Sensitivity Variable1 Sensitivity1 Variable2 Sensitivity2
var1     1           var2      0.76         var3      0.54
```

Where Am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: So, you're happy with the values for sensitivity, but you want a different format of this dataset, right?
Is `confusionMatrix` from the `caret` package?

Comment: Hi AntoniosK! Yes! I am happy with the values, bur the code rather than adding a new row at each application of the function adds new columns! Yes, it is confusionMatrix from caret package!

Answer (score 0):

Use this slightly changed approach:

```
k = grep("^var",colnames(data)) 

results<-data.frame(results <- sapply(k, FUN=function(x) {             # change to sapply
  cm = confusionMatrix(data=as.factor(data$ref), reference=as.factor(data[[x]]))
  data.frame(
    variable=names(data)[x],
    Sensitivity = unname(cm$byClass[1]),
    stringsAsFactors = F)}))     # add this to keep column names as a character variable

results = data.frame(t(results)) # transpose results
```

And your `results` data frame will look like

```
#    variable Sensitivity
# X1     var1        0.25
# X2     var2           0
# X3      var         0.5
# X4     var3           0
# X5     var5   0.2857143
```